# How to manage data that is loaded when user scrolls but it's also used in different places?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some data that it fetches when user scrolls, I was storing it in redux but now when I have to use same data again in another place, it can be through pagination numbers or again fetching on scroll I don't know how to treat this, should I show immediately all the data that was fetched previously and start fetching where he previously left? Or don't store it in redux at all and make requests to server again to fetch the data?

Comment: Wouldn't you also fetch "pages" on scroll, just display all of them at once?

Comment: What if I previously fetched 200 items, I wonder if it's good idea to show 200 items in the next page immediately @phry

Comment: It all really depends how you store that data. In one big array? Per "page"? And how you select it, too. All of it? Only what you want to display? Also, do you magage all that by yourself or do you use a api cache management solution like Redux Toolkit's RTK Query? Any answer you get would wildly differ on all of these factors.